# Tight bound on the number of divisors of n

Tags: number-theory, mathematical-foundations

The inner loop of this pseudocode runs only for the divisors of n

```
for i=1 to n:
   if(n%i==0):
      for j=1 to n:
         Do something in constant time
```

If I can get a bound on the number of divisor of n(The condition in the if statement) then I can get its time complexity.Please Help ?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to find the complexity of your C code? What is input?

Comment: Yes I want to find the time complexity of this code !

Comment: We are happy to help you, but programming questions is off-topic here. You should first clearly state what you want to solve, then provide a pseudocode with input, then what you think and have done, and your question. By the way, why do you loop $n$ times if $n$ is divisible by $i$?

Comment: if n is a power of 2 the inner loop runs log n times so its complexity is Theta(nlog(n)).I want the complexity for each value of n !

Comment: The number of divisors can be anything from 2 to roughly $n^{1/\log\log n}$, and is on average $\log n$ (in a certain precise sense). See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate) for more details.

Comment: If your concern is if its complexity is polynomial or not, it is not polynomial assuming $n$ is input (whose size is $\log{n}$). It is definitely exponential in size of $n$ or pseudo-polynomial  in $n$.

Comment: How Can it be exponential, the number of divisors do not increase at an exponential rate as n increases !

Comment: @PradeepKumar: There's the difference between "polynomial in n" and "polynomial in the size of n". The number 1,234,567,890 has just 10 digits. Size is about 31 bits.

Comment: Arguably, this would be better suited to [math.SE] since it's solely about properties of the divisor function, an object of number theory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the actual question is "Please give me tight bounds on the number of divisors of a given natural number", which is a question of pure mathematics, not computer science.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your input is $n$. I also assume that you know that we measure the time complexity of an algorithm as a function of input length to this algorithm which is $\log_2{n}$ in this case. Then even the following simple loop would take exponential time (as a function of input size)

```
for i=1 to n:
   print "hi"
end
```

since it loops $n$ times, where $n = 2^{\log_2{n}} = 2^{\text{input size}}$.

More precisely, its running time (as Yuval Filmus commented) is roughly $O(nn^{1/{\log{\log{n}}}})$ which is still exponential. But since your algorithm is $O(n^2)$ it is pseudo polynomial (polynomial in the numeric value of the input, not input size).

Comment: The inner loop only works for the divisors of n so the running time of this code would be (number of divisors of n multiplied by n ) so if we can get a bound on the divisors we can find its running time . Also for prime numbers (n=a prime number) the inner loop would run two times !

Comment: @PradeepKumar What you say is lower and upper bounds, I gave the upper bound. Since the lower and upper bounds are quite different, it makes sense to talk about average number of divisors which is $\log{n}$ and so in average it runs for $n\log{n}$ steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your test whether i is a divisor of n runs for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n, therefore the execution time is at least $\theta(n)$. You can easily reduce that to $\theta(n^{1/2})$ be finding divisors $i≤n^{1/2}$ and observing that with a divisor i, n / i is also a divisor.

Comment: If $i$ *is* a divisor, the nested loop costs $\Theta(n)$, so the complexity would be $\Theta(n\cdot(\text{the number of divisors of $n$}))$.